# How to solve pandas libs interval issue with py2app?

Tags: python, pandas, py2app

I have made a python bot that I want to export to an app in Mac. I have used py2app module for this purpose. The python code runs perfectly but the application made doesn't work and gives the following error. I'm using Mac Catalina 15.6 as of now and Python 3.7. I have latest modules downloaded for all required packages. Needless to say this isn't whole error script but these are the main errors. What could I do to solve this?
Error Message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas._libs.tslibs.base'
    KeyError: 'pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion'
    KeyError: 'pandas._libs.missing'
    KeyError: 'pandas._libs.hashtable'
    KeyError: 'pandas._libs.interval'
    2020-09-11 12:10:19.732 main[762:11200] main Error
    Unable to create basic Accelerated OpenGL renderer.
    Unable to create basic Accelerated OpenGL renderer.
    Core Image is now using the software OpenGL renderer. This will be slow.
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding pandas to the packages option in setup.py worked for me,

```
"""
This is a setup.py script generated by py2applet

Usage:
    python setup.py py2app
"""

from setuptools import setup

APP = ['automating_finances0.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {'packages': ['pandas']} <<<<<<<<

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Comment: it is useful for me

Answer (score 0):

```
pip uninstall pandas
pip install pandas
```